# changing the background colour onclick HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, colors, background, onclick

I'm doing some freelance work for someone and a key aspect of their website is to be able to change the colour of the background onclick of a button. I have not been able to do it with HTML5 and keep the main aspects of CSS. I am using the domain name http://tester01.uk/ to display the website.

Is there a way to change the color of the main container onclick?

If anybody could give me some advice that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know which container color should be changed, but I guess it can be done with jquery.

```
<script>
      $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.style2').css('background', '#777777')
      })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in straight javascript:

onclick="document.getElementById(ID of container element).style.backgroundColor='#ccc';"   (or other colour expression)